# ListView with image and text filtering by text

Tags: android, image, listview, text

Original post:
I have a ListView with image and text and a TextView to filter rows by text.
When I run my app it doesn't show the images and instead of text it shows the object reference.

Post Edited:
I have updated MainActivity.java and I added two new classes MeetingAdapter.java and MeetingFilter.java Now the problem is that my app is not filtering the results according the text searched

**main_activity_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Meeting name filter -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/find_meeting_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/find_meeting_name_hint"
    android:inputType="text" />

<!-- Meeting list -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/meeting_name_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**meeting_list_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<!-- Meeting image -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/meeting_image"
    android:layout_width="48dip"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:contentDescription="@string/meeting_image_description" />

<!-- Meeting name -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/meeting_name"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText findMeetingName;
    private MeetingAdapter meetingAdapter;
    private ListView meetingNameList;

    private ArrayList<Meeting> meetings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_layout);

        findMeetingName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.find_meeting_name);
        findMeetingName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
                MainActivity.this.meetingAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
                meetingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });

        meetings = new ArrayList<Meeting>();
        Meeting meeting = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            meeting = new Meeting();
            meeting.setId(i + 1);
            meeting.setName("Cita #" + (i + 1));
            meeting.setDescription("Descripción #" + (i + 1));
            meeting.setImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(), R.drawable.icon48x48_1));
            meeting.setInitialDate(new Date());
            meetings.add(meeting);
        }

        meetingAdapter = new MeetingAdapter(this, meetings);
        meetingNameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.meeting_name_list);
        meetingNameList.setAdapter(meetingAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MeetingAdapter.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MeetingAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<Meeting> meetings;

    public MeetingAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Meeting> meetings) {
        this.meetings = meetings;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return meetings.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return meetings.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup mainViewGroup) {
        View mRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meeting_list_item, mainViewGroup, false);

        // Se setean los valores para cada componente de la lista
        TextView meetingName = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.meeting_name);
        meetingName.setText(meetings.get(position).getName());
        ImageView meetingImage = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.meeting_image);
        meetingImage.setImageBitmap(meetings.get(position).getImage());

        return mRow;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        MeetingFilter filter = new MeetingFilter(meetings);
        return filter;
    }

}
```

**MeetingFilter.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.widget.Filter;

public class MeetingFilter extends Filter {

    //MeetingAdapter meetingAdapter;
    ArrayList<Meeting> meetings;

    public MeetingFilter(ArrayList<Meeting> meetings){
        //this.meetingAdapter = meetingAdapter;
        this.meetings = meetings;
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filteredResults = new FilterResults();
        if(constraint.length() == 0) {
            filteredResults.values = meetings;
            filteredResults.count = meetings.size();
            return filteredResults;
        }

        ArrayList<Meeting> filteredMeetings = new ArrayList<Meeting>();
        for (Meeting meeting : meetings) {
            // TODO Revisar problemas de internacionalización
            if(meeting.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                filteredMeetings.add(meeting);
            }
        }
        filteredResults.values = filteredMeetings;
        filteredResults.count = filteredMeetings.size();

        return filteredResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        meetings = (ArrayList<Meeting>) results.values;
        //meetingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**Meeting.java**

```
import java.util.Date;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Meeting {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private Bitmap image;

    private Date initialDate;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Date getInitialDate() {
        return initialDate;
    }

    public void setInitialDate(Date initialDate) {
        this.initialDate = initialDate;
    }

}
```

I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Pragnani mentioned above, you need to create a custom adapter like this:

```
public class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return list.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int itemData) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int itemPosition) 
    {
        return itemPosition;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View mainView, ViewGroup mainViewGroup) 
    {
        LayoutInflater maniInFlater = getLayoutInflater();
        View mRow = maniInFlater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout_layout, mainViewGroup, false);
        TextView sampleText = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.sample_id);
        return mRow;
    }
}
```

Then set this as your `ListView` adapter:

```
lv.setAdapter(new customAdapter());
```

Comment: I have updated MainActivity.java and I added two new classes MeetingAdapter.java and MeetingFilter.java Now the problem is that my app is not filtering the results according the text searched

Comment: @JohnBetts It's another question, I suggest you to open a new question for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are only using `TextView` in your `ArrayAdapter` 
i.e

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Meeting>(this, R.layout.meeting_list_item, R.id.meeting_name, meetings);
```

You are trying to print meeting names only in TextView, ArrayAdapter will take TextView as a resource to populate data in the list.
So `try to take a custom Adapter which extends ArrayAdapter or Base Adapter` or simply  use `SimpleAdapter`